# Trying To get text file from storage in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, file, text, storage

I'm trying to get text file from the storage.
Here is my code. It is catching `IOexception`, why?
I had created a button which lets me choose the text file but as soon as click on the 
file it does give me any path TOAST and it does not send the text to my text view.

Here is my code below:

```
package com.example.filechooser2;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.BufferUnderflowException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE = 1000;
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE =400 ;
Button b_load;
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b_load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_load);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            performFileSearch();
        }
    });

    //requesting permission

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE);
    }
}
```

This is where the code creates problem i think because
it shows the Exception error , please help

```
 // Reading Content
  private  String readText(String input)
  {
      File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),input);
      StringBuilder text =  new StringBuilder();
      try{
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
          String line;
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
          {
                text.append(line);
                text.append("\n");

            } br.close();
      }
      catch (IOException e){

         e.printStackTrace();
          Toast.makeText(this,"Messed up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      }
        return text.toString();

  }



// NOW TO GET FROM FILE SYSTEM
private void performFileSearch()
{
    Intent i = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("text/*");
    startActivityForResult(i,READ_REQUEST_CODE);


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK);
    {
        if(data != null)
        {
            Uri uri  = data.getData();
            String Path = uri.getPath();
            Path = Path.substring(Path.indexOf(":")+1);
            if(Path.contains("emulated"))
            {
                Path = Path.substring(Path.indexOf("0")+1);
            }
            Toast.makeText(this,""+Path,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            tv.setText(readText(Path));
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode==PERMISSION_REQUEST_STORAGE){

        if (grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permisssion Granted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Not Given",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of all of the path stuff. Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by that `Uri`.

Comment: can u explain where to re edit the path thing ? Plzz....

Comment: Google has [documentation covering the use of `openInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#open). [This sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.7/Diceware) and [this sample app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.7/ContentEditor) from [this book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) also show the use of `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `openInputStream()`.